# Ruby - can I shorten this 7 line method that declares and returns an array

Tags: ruby, methods, refactoring

Seems like this would be a fairly common pattern - declaring the array and returning it:

```
def self.show_day_rows(days, month, year, offset)
  daylines=[]
  1.step(days,7).each do |line_starts_with|
    daylines << CalDay.line_of_day_nums(month, year, line_starts_with, offset)
  end
  daylines
end
```

Is there a way to shorten this but still be legible?

Comment: You probably want to ask this on [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com). It's for these sort of questions.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belongs on Code Review 

Answer (score 2):

```
def self.show_day_rows(days, month, year, offset)
  1.step(days,7).map do |line_starts_with|
    CalDay.line_of_day_nums(month, year, line_starts_with, offset)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

A slight variant of @tihorn's answer:

```
def self.show_day_rows(days, month, year, offset)
  1.step(days,7).inject([]) do |daylines, line_starts_with|
    daylines << CalDay.line_of_day_nums(month, year, line_starts_with, offset)
  end
end
```